# What is this device? (from historical photo)

Tags: identification, radio, vacuum-tube, history

Anybody know what this might be?

It's from an old photo with my grandfather as a teenager who went on to work on radar during the war and later for "His Masters Voice" repairing televisions.  Accompanied by Every-Ready battery and box labelled "Ediswan" (another battery perhaps?).  Device could be home made.

Would love to know what it is.

fwiw: photo was taken in NSW, Australia.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A prototype time machine for H. G. Wells? Perhaps a homemade radio?

Comment: That would be a radio of some sort, you can see a large coil on the right. Hard to tell more than that.
That said, this question will probably be end up being closed as off topic.

Comment: I guess an AM radio receiver, the regenerative ones were popular as home build. In fact there were 'combo' valves designed for that (triode+pentode).  http://philsvalveradiosite.co.uk/philsvalveradiosite/simple2valvetrfreceiver_1.htm is an example

Comment: On the ground, on the right, is an Ediswan "balanced capacity accumulator" made at the Ponders End, Middlesex manufacturing site. Edison Swan Electric started using the "brand name" of Ediswan starting around the beginning of WW I (1914-1916, I think) and as a segue into being a "war products manufacturer." Obviously, the Ever-Ready "B" battery was a "high tension" (HT) battery used to create the plate voltages required by vacuum tubes. Ediswan also made those, but I'm guessing the Ever-Ready at the time was cheaper or easier to get. For the radio receiver on the chair, I'd look for "Telsen."

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great response.  We were guessing a vacuum tube radio, but weren't sure.